# How to run GitHub Next.js Build workflow with missing config?

Tags: github, next.js, github-actions

In my GitHub repository, I set up a workflow that checks whether you can build the NextJS website.
But this isn't working since a config file (which has a secret key that I don't want to show in GitHub), is not there.
Is there a way to create a config file with a key only for GitHub actions, or shall I just remove the building workflow?

Comment: If I understand it correctlly, [you would like to store secrets, that only github actions can access?](https://github.com/Azure/actions-workflow-samples/blob/f9eaaa571306eef17d74d254b02c2427a994f301/assets/create-secrets-for-GitHub-workflows.md)

Comment: @TDiblik Yeah, but it doesn't even need to be secret. (The token is a JWT Token). Shall I just create the file in the workflow run via echo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding the following to my workflow yaml:

```
- name: Creating Config
          run: printf "const config = {jwtToken:'example'};export default config;" >> config.ts && yarn prettier --tab-width 4 --single-quote --write ./config.ts
```